# admob not running in game loop

Tags: java, android, admob, surfaceview

ok im making a small game sort of like flappy bird in the sence that the start page, main game and game over screen are all in my main gameloop i switch the images being drawn on the canvas by changing a veriable called gameState ie: gameState == 0 (start page), gameState == 1 (main game), gameState == 2 (gameover screen) all works fine but the problem am having is that when i try to load an ad from admob it fails while the loop is running even tho the ad request is called from my main activity and the custome surfaceView that contains my gameloop is run in its own separate tread

main activity class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId(unitId_Banner);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);

    sView = new SView(this, this.getResources());

    RelativeLayout mainLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

    mainLayout.addView(sView);
    mainLayout.addView(adView, adParams); 
    adView.bringToFront(); 

    setContentView(mainLayout); 
    adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build());
}
```

gameloop class

```
public void run(){
    while(running){
        if(!holder.getSurface().isValid()){
            continue;
        }
        canvas = null;
        try{
            canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized(holder){
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                framesSkipped = 0;
                update();
                draw(canvas);

                timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                sleepTime = (int)(FRAME_PERIOD - timeDiff);

                if(sleepTime > 0){
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);   
                    }catch(InterruptedException e){}
                }
                while(sleepTime < 0 && framesSkipped < MAX_FRAME_SKIPS){
                    update();
                    sleepTime += FRAME_PERIOD; 
                    framesSkipped++;
                }
            }
        }finally{
            if(canvas != null){
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

if i were to remove the while loop in the gameloop run method the ad loads fine can anybody help me pleads

```
03-04 02:47:30.997: I/Ads(277): Starting ad request.
03-04 02:47:58.218: W/Ads(277): There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
03-04 02:47:58.227: W/Ads(277): Failed to load ad: 0
```

Comment: try this let `setContentView(mainLayout);` be the last function in your `onCreate` method. or probably the adview functions be the first lines in your oncreate after super.onCreate

Comment: what's the failure - show your logcat

Comment: hey elitz tried it but no luck any other sugestions

Comment: william there you go hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up having to use.tread wait() until ad loaded still not 100% satisfied but it works